# Can't install Android plugin for Eclipse on MacOS X (Leopard)

Tags: android, eclipse, plugins

When I try to install the Android plugin for Eclipse on MacOS X (Leopard), I get the error:

> Cannot create tempfile for site.xml Permission denied

I'm not sure what permissions the system is referring to.

I have set this up on a Linux distro with no trouble at all.

Answer (score 0):

Is this displayed in a dialog in Eclipse? Is there a button to show more details?

Which directory is your Eclipse installation in?  Within your home directory, or somewhere else on the system that you wouldn't normally have permission to write to?

Which step of the installation is this?  While trying to locate the plugin using the "Install New Software..." dialog, or somewhere else?

Comment: The error message was displayed in Eclipse.

The Eclipse was installed in the /Applications folder.

This step occurs while trying to locate the plugin using "Install New Software...".  I had to download the plugin to my local system because I could not use the Android plugin URL.

Have you actually  gotten this working on MacOS X?

Comment: Yeah, I have it working. My Eclipse installation is within my home directory, and the plugin install worked fine as far as I remember.

Answer (score 0):

As it turns out I had to install Eclipse and apply updates, including the addition of the Android plugin, as root user.